How can I validate two dates in a model with Pydantic? end_date greater than init_date
I have a Pydantic model with two dates in it (init_date and end_date)
I need to ensure that end_date is after init_date, before trying to add to database (it's necessary to calculate the delta in days with these two dates).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In this case you would want to use a model validator. By specifying mode="after" we can configure some custom logic to run on the model once the underlying data has been validated.
https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#model-validators
An example of what this would look like:
from datetime import datetime

from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    init_date: datetime
    end_date: datetime

    @model_validator(mode="after")
    def _validate_dates(self):
        if self.init_date > self.end_date:
            raise ValueError("init_date must be before end_date")
        return self

